# Print current age given the date of birth

Tags: python, datetime

I have to make a code outside of a function where I print the current age given the input of the date of birth. So far I've got this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
birth1 = input("Input your date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy):")

currentDate = date.today()
birth2 = datetime.strptime(birth1, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
age = currentDate - birth2
```

But I'm stuck here. How can I make it so the var "age" gets the current age from the person so I can later print it in something like this:

```
print(age, "years old")
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, the 'age' is a timedelta https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects, you can gather the count of days and divide by a years worth of days: `age.days / 365 == 23.55`

Comment: `int(age.days / 365.2425)` if you'd like to take leap year into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

See below code -it should work for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
age = currentDate.year - birth2.year
if currentDate.month < birth2.month or \
  (currentDate.month == birth2.month and currentDate.day < birth2.day):
  age -= 1
print(age, "years old")
```